# Add code to html table to modify td cell’s data content

Tags: typescript, next.js, node.js-typeorm

I want to do something like this but do not know the syntax:

Display the month from int data:

{ my date = new Date(); my date.Month = ({datadate} - 1).toString(default, { month: long})}

Database data is 12, I want to display “December”

Using typeorm and nextjs

I wrote it like that, the bottom of my laptop bulged, and I need a new battery. So, haven’t done much else

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.